# Issue with loading on pushed page

Tags: ionic2

I have some flow on my app that, in some moment, I push a page to the stack and, on that page, I call a loading dialog for some data load. The problem is that the loading dialog didn't showed up. Then I realized that when I got back to the previous page, the loading was there, under my page that was being showed up. If in my navigation flow, instead of `nav.push` I use `nav.setRoot`, it works fine, so I think it's some glitch with that navigation stack. I really wanna use `nav.push`cause it makes more sense for my app.
Any ideas?

EDIT:

my function that call the page:

```
onViewUnidade(unidade){
    if (unidade.tipo == "Unidade Consumidora"){
        this.nav.push(UnidadeConsumidoraPage, unidade);
    }else if (unidade.tipo == "Usina"){
        this.nav.push(UsinaPage, unidade);
    }
}
```

my onInit method:

```
 ngOnInit(){
    console.log("show loading");
    this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: "some message"
    });  
    this.loading.present();
 }
```

My console.log executes, and I even didn't dismissed it, so I could see it correctly. The Loading and LoadingController are properly imported and injected.

EDIT 2:
I noticed that issue only happens when the page that redirects to my last page with the loading is a modal. If I change it for a regular page, it works correctly. Also, tried to dismiss the modal and `popToRoot` before navigate to new page... but still gotting same issue. Any ideas?

Comment: update the post with the code.

Comment: @Aravind updated it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got my answer on documentation:
Instead of injecting navigation controller, when you wanted to navigate from an overlay component (popover, modal, alert, etc), we have to get a reference of the root NavController in our app, using the getRootNav() method:

```
this.appCtrl.getRootNav().push(SecondPage);
```

Hope this helps who got the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at LoadingOptions

```
export interface LoadingOptions {
    spinner?: string;
    content?: string;
    cssClass?: string;
    showBackdrop?: boolean;
    dismissOnPageChange?: boolean;
    delay?: number;
    duration?: number;
}
```

You can set `dismissOnPageChange`(to true). Make sure you dismiss the loading dialog or set `duration`.

Comment: think you got it wrong. My problem is not on dismiss it, is on show. It's showing behind my pushed page

Comment: If you can share your app, I will be able to help you out. I have done similar implementation.

Comment: Unfortunately, that app is private and its code is confidential, but updated the question with more information. Thanks in advance!